# How can I combine two data frames and, where there is a match on a common field, merge the data into a single record?

Tags: r, join

I have two data frames (`df1` and `df2`) which I wish to combine and, where there is a match on a common field, combine those rows' data, otherwise simply add them to the resulting data frame.

They share a common field (`specimenid`) and where there are matches between `df1` and `df2`, I wish to combine those individual rows' data to produce a single row, featuring the fields of both data frames.

For example, my data frames might be something like this:

```
df1:

specimenid   firstname    age
001          bob          45
004          stuart       65
005          eunice       43
006          robert       20
007          james        40

df2:

specimenid  surname    salary    department
001         hastings   £45,000   sales
002         smith      £28,500   accounting
007         bond       £150,000  international relations
008         jennings   £50,000   contracts
```

And the resulting data frame should look like this:

```
specimenid  firstname  age  surname   salary    department
001         bob        45   hastings  £45,000   sales
002         NA         NA   smith     £28,500   accounting
004         stuart     65   NA        NA        NA
005         eunice     43   NA        NA        NA
006         robert     20   NA        NA        NA
007         james      40   bond      £150,000  international relations
008         NA         NA   jennings  £50,000   contracts
```

The resulting data frame will be a combination of the data frames' rows where there is a match on `specimenid` in both `df1` and `df2` and for those records where there is no match, they will be added as new rows with `NA`s populating the unmatched fields.

**I want to include the data from both data frames regardless of whether there is a match or not.  If there is a match, then I wish to combine the data frames' rows into a single entry.**

I feel that this is a clear example and explanation, but if further clarification is needed then I will update the question.

Comment: with tidyverse, full_join(df1, df2, by = "specimenid")

Comment: `merge(df1,df2, by="specimenid",all=T)`  with `BaseR`

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.